# Getting error when I try to post data to Mvc Restful api on my android app

Tags: android

This is my first app on android. I've got a restfull service which was created on .net mvc. There is a login method which return a token key but I couldnt pass the parameters to the service. its returns

```
> {"message":"An error has occurred.","exceptionMessage":"Object
> reference not set to an instance of an
> object.","exceptionType":"System.NullReferenceException","stackTrace":"
> at
> artimesajMobil.RestApi.Controllers.LoginController.LoginOl(Kullanici
> kullanici)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n  
> at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass13.<GetExecutor>b__c(Object
> instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.Execute(Object
> instance, Object[] arguments)\r\n   at
> System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.<>c__DisplayClass5.<ExecuteAsync>b__4()\r\n
> at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpers.RunSynchronously[TResult](Func`1
> func, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}
```

my android code is :

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://localhost:8890/api/Login");
            post.setHeader("content-type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            try
            {
            List<NameValuePair> namevaluepairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test"));
            namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1907"));
            namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin", "8787"));
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs,HTTP.UTF_8));

            HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            String result = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            MyResult.setText(result);
            }
            catch(ClientProtocolException e){
                MyResult.setText(e.hashCode());
            }
            catch(IOException e){
                MyResult.setText(e.hashCode());

            }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:-

```
                List<NameValuePair> namevaluepairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", "test"));
                namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", "1907"));
                namevaluepairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("pin", "8787"));    


        try{
                        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
                        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(namevaluepairs));
                        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                        is = entity.getContent();
                    }catch(Exception e){
                        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
                    }

                //convert response to string
                try{
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    is.close();

                    result=sb.toString();
                    //System.out.println("query Result:----------"+result);
                }catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }
```